# How to edit applications context menu in gnome

Tags: gnome

Gnome by default doesn't provide the functionalities of "Shading window" and "Keep below other windows" (which can be found in KDE Plasma and Cinnamon). I have been able to activate those functionalities using `wmctrl` and I have created keybindings for them and they work fine.
Now the problem is, I may sometimes unable to recall those keybindings if I am in a hurry. So, I thought of editing the applications Right-click context menu and adding those two options (Shade and Keep below other windows). I am talking about the menu which appears on right-clicking an application's title bar.
Is there any way to 'add' items to that menu? May be with editing some configuration files or with an extension? FYI: I am using Gnome 3.36.4 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out? I am looking to do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote [a tutorial](https://retiolus.net/posts/add-custom-context-menu-option-for-firefox-in-gnome/) about this; I hope it will help you.

To summarise:

1. Locate and copy the Firefox `.desktop` file

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
   ```
2. Modify the .desktop File:

   Find the `Actions` line and append `new-profilename-window;` to the end. For example:

   ```
   Actions=new-window;new-private-window;new-profilename-window;
   ```

   Then, add the following section at the bottom of the file:

   ```
   [Desktop Action new-profilename-window]
   Name=Open a New profilename Window
   Exec=firefox -P "profilename"
   ```

   Make sure to replace `profilename` with the name of the Firefox profile you want to open.
3. Reload GNOME Shell.

   You can do this by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, typing <kbd>R</kbd>, and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.